# VBA Userform user signature input into spreadsheet

Tags: vba, image, excel, picturebox

I'm new to InkPicture but I like to use it for user to put signature into the form.

I can't seem to save the signature (inkpicture) to the spreadsheet it just inputs it as 0 into the cell I specify.

`With UserForm1.InkPicture1.InkEnabled = False Set.Ink 
Me.InkPicture1.Ink 
.InkEnabled = True End With`
`lrDep = Sheets("Deploy").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Sheets("Deploy").Cells(lrDep + 1, "A").Value = TBox1.Text Sheets("Deploy").Cells(lrDep + 1, "B").Value = TBox2.Text Sheets("Deploy").Cells(lrDep + 1, "C").Value = TBox3.Text Sheets("Deploy").Cells(lrDep + 1, "D").Value = TBox4.Text 
Sheets("Deploy").Cells(lrDep + 1, "G").Value = InkPicture1.Ink`

Could someone please help me. 
Thank you.

Comment: @war360: Please do not use comments to post raw code, especially without any sense (explanation)

Comment: More information on adding code to a post can be found here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @war360, please learn how to put code in your question (there is a button on the top of the wysiwyg when writing a question). I've just added the code in the comments to it, so please accept and delete your comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but will help you on your way, comment if you have any questions.

First you will have to have a text box on your form that requires the asset ID,
this will have to be amended to match your current form.

```
Dim RowN As Long
Dim SearchTxt
SearchTxt = TextBox1.Value 'This should be set to the text box name on the form of the  asset ID
    On Error Resume Next
    RowN = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SearchTxt, Range("A:A"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If RowN > 0 Then

            'your code here if matches
            MsgBox RowN ' display the row number

        Else

            'your code here if no match, possibly add new row of data
            MsgBox "No match found" 
End If
```

Now you can amend each line of code to use the found row number, for example:

`Sheets("Data").Cells("A" & RowN).Value = TextBox1.Txt`

If I was creating this form, I would add a search button to check the asset ID and where it finds a match, all the text boxes would then be populated with the current values of the data, these can then be amended before adding back to the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The following will look for the ID in Column A and if found will use that row to enter the data, this assumes that the ID is stored in TextBox1.Text, amend as required:

```
Private Sub SB1_Click()

Dim lrREG As Long, lrB As Long, lrDep As Long, lrDis As Long, lrDAT As Long
Dim foundID As Range


        Set foundID = Sheets("Data").Range("A:A").Find(What:=TextBox1.Text, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not foundID Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("Data").Cells(foundID.Row, "A").Value = TextBox1.Text
            Sheets("Data").Cells(foundID.Row, "B").Value = TextBox2.Text
            Sheets("Data").Cells(foundID.Row, "C").Value = TextBox3.Text
        Else
            lrDAT = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Sheets("Data").Cells(lrDAT, "A").Value = TextBox1.Text
            Sheets("Data").Cells(lrDAT, "B").Value = TextBox2.Text
            Sheets("Data").Cells(lrDAT, "C").Value = TextBox3.Text
        End If

    lrREG = Sheets("Register").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Register").Cells(lrREG + 1, "A").Value = TextBox1.Text
    Sheets("Register").Cells(lrREG + 1, "B").Value = TextBox2.Text
    Sheets("Register").Cells(lrREG + 1, "C").Value = TextBox3.Text

    lrB = Sheets("Built").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Built").Cells(lrB + 1, "A").Value = TB1.Text
    Sheets("Built").Cells(lrB + 1, "B").Value = TB2.Text
    Sheets("Built").Cells(lrB + 1, "C").Value = TB3.Text
    Sheets("Built").Cells(lrB + 1, "D").Value = TB4.Text
    Sheets("Built").Cells(lrB + 1, "E").Value = TB5.Text
    Sheets("Built").Cells(lrB + 1, "F").Value = TB6.Text

    lrDep = Sheets("Deploy").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Deploy").Cells(lrDep + 1, "A").Value = TBox1.Text
    Sheets("Deploy").Cells(lrDep + 1, "B").Value = TBox2.Text
    Sheets("Deploy").Cells(lrDep + 1, "C").Value = TBox3.Text
    Sheets("Deploy").Cells(lrDep + 1, "D").Value = TBox4.Text
    Sheets("Deploy").Cells(lrDep + 1, "E").Value = TBox5.Text
    Sheets("Deploy").Cells(lrDep + 1, "F").Value = TBox6.Text

    lrDis = Sheets("Dispose").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Dispose").Cells(lrB + 1, "A").Value = TextBo1.Text
    Sheets("Dispose").Cells(lrDis + 1, "B").Value = TextBo2.Text
    Sheets("Dispose").Cells(lrDis + 1, "C").Value = TextBo3.Text
    Sheets("Dispose").Cells(lrDis + 1, "D").Value = TextBo4.Text
    Sheets("Dispose").Cells(lrDis + 1, "E").Value = TextBo5.Text
    Sheets("Dispose").Cells(lrDis + 1, "F").Value = TextBo6.Text
End Sub
```